# Reading and setting z-index values with jQuery on Webkit browsers

Tags: jquery, css, webkit, z-index

`jQuery("#X").css("z-index");` always returns "auto" on Webkit browsers. Works ok on Firefox.

It also appears that you can't set the z-index with something like: `jQuery("#X").css("z-index",5);`

Test case follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>jQuery CSS Z-index Fail</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#X").css("z-index",5);       
        $("#Y").append($("#X").css("z-index"));
      });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
      h1 {z-index: 3;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
     <h1 id="X">Some Text</h1>
     <div id="Y"> Z-index is: </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You NEED to specify position to use z-index.

```
<h1 id="X" style='position:relative;'>Some Text</h1>
```

fixes it immediately in Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

try

`zIndex` instead of `z-index`.

Answer (score 1):

A known issue with Webkit browsers, detailed [here](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/9667)

> I understand it being confusing that the computed z-index is auto when
>   you've specifically set one with .css, but RAMilewski makes a good
>   point that computed z-index will be different in different browsers.
>   We could lie (in a sense) and say that what was set is being applied
>   so that return values are consistent, or users can realize that the
>   z-index will not be applied without setting the other styles to make
>   z-index work. I'm closing wontfix as I suspect this will not be
>   something we will change, but if anyone disagrees, we can reopen in
>   the future.

Marked resolution is **Won't fix**. So don't expect this to go away anytime soon.

---

Jqueryu UI's [zIndex function](http://api.jqueryui.com/zIndex/) seems to have the same problem BTW: