# What is wrong with this statement?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, z-index

I have several images I am manipulating in an animation with CSS via jQuery. All but one of the basic manipulations is having obvious effect; however,

```
jQuery('#' + sites[index].replace('.', '') + 'raw').css('z-index', size);
```

does not seem to have ever set the z-index on them; Chrome's Inspect Element pulls CSS, including absolute positioning and top and left placements, but besides objects with a higher size sometimes appearing behind objects with a lower size, Chrome does not see a z-index on that object, ever.

I've run into a couple of subtleties; some positioning is needed, for which absolute positioning looks sufficient. If I examine:

```
jQuery('#' + sites[index].replace('.', '') + 'raw').length
```

then that has length 1, as would be expected.

What else do I need to do to get a z-index CSS assignment via jQuery?

Thanks,

Comment: Does your selector work, and select what you expect it to select?

Comment: I believe that the selector is working from inspection and from having length 1. Also, the same selector is used elsewhere and I don't see any problems with the others.

Comment: Well can the element be adjusted with the z-index to start?

Comment: Where `size` is defined?

Comment: console.log(jQuery('#' + sites[index].replace('.', '') + 'raw')) ?

Comment: Have you tried `css({'position' : 'relative', 'z-index' : size});`? (I can't work out, from your text, if this element, or others, have `position: absolute` set) And does `size` contain the value you expect?

Comment: Does your sites[index] string have more than one '.' in them that you're attempting to replace? String.prototype.replace will only replace the first '.'

Comment: @matthias_h: Did you mean to type `css({'z-index': size})`? It should make no difference to jQuery which version of that css call you use.

Comment: @DavidThomas, is it a problem for the elements to have absolute positioning? They are meant to be absolutely positioned.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie sorry yes, was wrong - just found this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6476360/reading-and-setting-z-index-values-with-jquery-on-webkit-browsers  maybe still true that webkit needs postion set together with z-index

Comment: No, not at all, I phrased badly is all; I couldn't tell if non-`static` positioning was in use.

Comment: @Mithon, they are all of the form domain.tld, with one dot each.

Comment: @Hindmost, size is calculated elsewhere as a width of something like 100-300. Everywhere I've inspected it, it has been a decimal value within bounds for what I expect.

Comment: and just found this with a kind of workaround at the end: https://forum.jquery.com/topic/plugin-google-chrome-css-zindex-not-being-set  , maybe this helps? Not knowing about the previous elements in the example it's just a guess.

Comment: Exactly what does that selector string look like when jQuery sees it? Just verifying the `.length` tells you that the selector matched *something*, but not necessary the *right* something. *edit* Basically what @Arthur wrote above - inspect the element that jQuery found and verify that it's the proper target of your code.

Comment: @Pointy, it logs something like '[img#cjshnameraw, context: document, selector: "#cjshnameraw", jquery: "1.11.1", constructor: function, toArray: function…]'. If I inspect the element in question, I get '<img src="/img/cjsh.name.raw.png" id="cjshnameraw" style="left: 1490.1158504429486px; width: 238.0902330037943px; top: 324.8992246885771px;">'. That is what I want (the rest of) it to be, modulo the absence of a z-index.

Comment: @JonathanHayward I'm going to look at the jQuery source, but as a (possibly fruitless) experiment have you tried "zIndex" instead of "z-index"?

Comment: P.S. My source, if you want to look at its half-baked present state, is at http://portfolio.jsh.name/. Present behaviour in Chrome on my display is to display images rotating through space, but sometimes a larger one behind a smaller one.

Comment: Well setting `z-index` on an `<img>` tag like that is working fine for me. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gxc2k2kr/1/)

Comment: Just to be sure - the proposal to set z-index and position at the same time like david thomas proposed earlier was already tried and failed? As far as I understood this is one of some webkit issues despite the css already states a position value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `size` is a floating point value. I haven't had any luck setting the `z-index` value to anything but an integer. Try using `Math.round(size)` instead.

Comment: Or simply `~~size` which is much faster (if you only want integer truncation).